# Как сделать отправку данных?

Tags: javascript

есть отправка данных при нажатии enter

```js
input.on('keyup', function(e) {
 var curUsername = user.join();
 if (e.keyCode === 13 && input.val().length > 0) {
  var getTxt = input.val();
  messages.push({
   user: curUsername,
   message: getTxt
  });
  input.val('');
 }
});
```

как сделать чтобы данные отправлялись и по нажатию enter и по нажатию на submit с id #send

Comment: используйте document.getelementbyid('тут айди сабмита'); и повесьте на него обработчик

Comment: Спасибо, подойдёт)

Answer (score 0):

```
var submit = document.getElementById('send');
submit.onclick = function () {
    var curUsername = user.join();
    if (input.val().length > 0) {
        var getTxt = input.val();
        messages.push({
            user: curUsername,
            message: getTxt
        });
    input.val('');
    }
}
```